# How to train two datasets in SVM binary class

Tags: python, svm

I want to train two (AND and NAND) datasets for SVM and then want to predict if it is AND or NAND. For example,
class AND:

```
X1 = [[0,0,],[0,1,],[1,0,],[1,1]];  y1 = [0,0,0,1]
```

class NAND:

```
X2 = [[0,0,],[0,1,],[1,0,],[1,1,]];  y2 = [1,1,1,0]
```

In classification, there is only option to define `classsification.fit(X, y)`.
Is it possible to fit all together as `classsification.fit(X1,X2,y1,y2)`?
If anyone can give me a idea how to fit two datasets in SVM classifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is not to fit the two data sets, but to modify your data set and label set, where the data set should be:

```
>>> X1 = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
>>> y1 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])
>>> X2 = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
>>> y2 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0])
>>> X = np.concatenate([np.concatenate([X1, y1[:, None]], axis=1), np.concatenate([X2, y2[:, None]], axis=1)])
>>> X
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

The label set should be:

```
>>> y = np.repeat([0, 1], 4)
>>> y
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Where 0 represents class AND and 1 represents class NAND (you can also replace them with any two other numbers).

Now you can train and use them like this:

```
>>> svc = SVC().fit(X, y)
>>> svc.predict(np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]))
array([0, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, specially for the concatenate function.